# What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?

Tags: android, view, android-view, android-viewholder

What is the main purpose of such methods as `setTag()` and `getTag()` of `View` type objects?

Am I right in thinking that I can associate any number of objects with a single View?

Answer (score 672, accepted):

Let's say you generate a bunch of views that are similar. You could set an `OnClickListener` for each view individually:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ... );
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ... );
 ...
```

Then you have to create a unique `onClick` method for each view even if they do the similar things, like:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    doAction(1); // 1 for button1, 2 for button2, etc.
}
```

This is because `onClick` has only one parameter, a `View`, and it has to get other information from instance variables or final local variables in enclosing scopes. What we really want is to get information *from the views themselves*.

Enter `getTag`/`setTag`:

```
button1.setTag(1);
button2.setTag(2);
```

Now we can use the same OnClickListener for every button:

```
listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doAction(v.getTag());
    }
};
```

It's basically a way for views to have *memories*.

Comment: @Matthew Willis but we can do that using the view.getId() too. is not it ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller you could, but with setTag() you can put any object you want, even custom classes - so you can use them to persist a reference to the data that the view is displaying

Comment: What should i do if i only want to change the background color of the button that is clicked ???

I am getting the  position by getTag().

Comment: @Sagar: `public void ui_click(View view){ if(20==((int)view.getTag())) view.setBackgroundColor(colorInt); }` should do the trick for the color part. 20 is just a placeholder for the validating position of your View.

Comment: I think this is the old way. the new way is to use generic arguments which provides type safety. but this is good nevertheless.

Answer (score 142):

I'd like to add few words.

Although using `get/setTag(Object)` seems to be very useful in the particular case of a ViewHolder pattern, I'd recommend to think twice before using it in other cases. There is almost always another solution with better design.

The main reason is that code like that becomes unsupportable pretty quickly.

- It is non-obvious for other developers what you designed to store as tag in the view. The methods `setTag/getTag` are not descriptive at all.
- It just stores an `Object`, which requires to be cast when you want to `getTag`. You can get unexpected crashes later when you decide to change the type of stored object in the tag.
- Here's a real-life story: We had a pretty big project with a lot of adapters, async operations with views and so on. One developer decided to `set/getTag` in his part of code, but another one had already set the tag to this view. In the end, someone couldn't find his own tag and was very confused. It cost us several hours to find the bug.

`setTag(int key, Object tag)` looks much better, cause you can generate unique keys for every tag (using [id resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id)), but there is a significant restriction for Android < 4.0. From Lint docs:

> Prior to Android 4.0, the implementation of View.setTag(int, Object)
>   would store the objects in a static map, where the values were
>   strongly referenced. This means that if the object contains any
>   references pointing back to the context, the context (which points to
>   pretty much everything else) will leak. If you pass a view, the view
>   provides a reference to the context that created it. Similarly, view
>   holders typically contain a view, and cursors are sometimes also
>   associated with views.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! ... Do you happen to know if what is in the tag gets restored between activity recreations?

Answer (score 28):

We can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` to set and get custom objects as per our requirement. The `setTag()` method takes an argument of type `Object`, and `getTag()` returns an `Object`.

For example,

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Ramkailash");
p.setId(2000001);
button1.setTag(p);
```

Answer (score 22):

For web developers, this seems to be the equivalent to data-..

Answer (score 16):

This is very useful for custom `ArrayAdapter` using. It is some kind of optimization. There `setTag` used as reference to object that references on some parts of layout (that displaying in `ListView`) instead of `findViewById`.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvPost;
    TextView tvDate;
    ImageView thumb;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem, null);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.tvPost = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postTitleLabel);
        vh.tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postDateLabel);
        vh.thumb = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postThumb);
        convertView.setTag(vh);
    }
            ....................
}
```

Answer (score 14):

> Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 14):

Setting of TAGs is really useful when you have a ListView and want to recycle/reuse the views. In that way the ListView is becoming very similar to the newer RecyclerView.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
ViewHolder holder = null;

if ( convertView == null )
{
    /* There is no view at this position, we create a new one. 
       In this case by inflating an xml layout */
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);  
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.toggleOk = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById( R.id.togOk );
    convertView.setTag (holder);
}
else
{
    /* We recycle a View that already exists */
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag ();
}

// Once we have a reference to the View we are returning, we set its values.

// Here is where you should set the ToggleButton value for this item!!!

holder.toggleOk.setChecked( mToggles.get( position ) );

return convertView;
}
```