# android : has any view something like hidden value?

Tags: android, view, hidden

I wonder, has any standart view (imageview, imagebutton, textview, button etc) something like hidden value ?? so i need set each item this value and then, for example, get it from view in onclick event.

error log

```
07-11 13:06:23.263: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at com.artox.relax.inf.RestaurantListBaseActivity$RestaurantListAdapter.getView(RestaurantListBaseActivity.java:95)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1521)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:900)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-11 13:06:23.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(989):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view

Comment: my app crashed ImageButton phones = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.item_phones_button);
   phones.setTag("asd");

Comment: Can you provide error log, please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to set visibility to any View instance, you can do this:

```
View myView = (View)findViewById(R.id.myview);
myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//or
myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//or
myView.setVisibility(View.HIDDEN);
```

You can check the doc here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setContentDescription(String str) and getContentDescription() with all the views you mentioned.

BUT

thats not the right way to handle this matter. you should either extend either the view class or the onclicklistener

for example:

```
 public class myClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

        private int hiddenValue;
        public myClickListener(int hiddenValue){
            this.hiddenValue=hiddenValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hiddenValue++;
        }

    }
```

and then you call it with .setonlicklistener(new myClickListener(5));