# An easy way to identify child views

Tags: android, layout, view, viewgroup

I am adding views to a layout at run time.
thee views are like so:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll1">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll2" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv1" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

(I took a lot out to make it simple)

Now in code I am adding any number of these to a layout. How then do I access the ImageViews and TextViews in each addition of this view?

Currently I have this complicated way going through each child and doing a

```
if (View instanceof ImageView)
```

if I were to call `parentView.getChildAt(0)` (where parent view is ll2) would this always return iv1? and at "1" would this always return tv1?

Then I have been storing these objects in a vector of itself, to call on them later.

Is there an easier way of doing this? Like when I first add the whole thing, is there a way I can just set the sources of the image views, and set the text of the textviews without having to go and find them this way?

Comment: You could use tagging, setTag http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inflated your view,find it's children and set a specific Tag for each child(use [`setTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) ).When you need to recognize,use [`getTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29).You can find good idea in about usage of getTag and setTag in [What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5291726/1043882) and [Android:setTag() and getTag() usage for changing the controls..](http://jongladwin.blogspot.de/2010/03/androidsettag-and-gettag-usage-for.html)

Comment: I can't understand why these people stop behind only accepting the Answer but not voting it up!