# Reading a tag from a textview

Tags: android

I am setting a tag on a textview using the following code

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("New Item");
tv.setTag("1");
```

How can I read the tag value I have set for this?

Comment: Using `getTag` of course. Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view it explains tags nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set tag with key also, so that you can set multiple tags with one component

like

```
tv.setTag(R.id.textView1, "1");
```

while getting you can do like

```
tv.getTag(R.id.textView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If theres setTag there should also be getTag, use:

```
tv.getTag();
```