# if else statement in android

Tags: android

I was new in Android and found some good tutorials on the internet, so I tried a simple activity with an `if-else` statement. I'm trying "correct and wrong" prompt/`Toast`:

```
Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
       page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                if (iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane1)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane2)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please put an answer",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane3)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

       });
```

I'm not sure what is wrong in my `if-else` statement but never prompts at all. I tried removing the `(iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane3))` and `(iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane2))` then it only shows the wrong Toast. I can't get seem to make the correct to prompt me.

Here is the full code of my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final Random imagerandom = new Random();

private static final Integer[] Imagesnumber = 
    { R.drawable.airplane1, R.drawable.airplane2, R.drawable.airplane3, };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Integer a = Imagesnumber[imagerandom.nextInt(Imagesnumber.length)];
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    View nextButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View V) {
              int resource = Imagesnumber[imagerandom.nextInt(Imagesnumber.length)];
              iv.setImageResource(resource);
         }
    });
    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
       page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                if (iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane1)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane2)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please put an answer",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane3)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

       });




}

}
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly, are you trying to see what image is displayed in yout `iv1`?

Comment: yes i`m trying to see if the imaged displayed in iv1 is correct or wrong using the if else i`m not quite sure what is wrong in my if else statement

Comment: you are missing the else condition.i mean the condition which doesnt satisfy the 3 of the ifs you specified

Comment: the issue is you are trying to see if the Image view is equal to the Id of a drawable these are things that will never be equal as the are different objects. you may want to look for a way to get the current drawable from the imageview and then see what that equals.

Comment: You're comparing integers to ImageViews. That won't work. R.drawable.airplane1 is not an image itself, it's an int that servers as a resource identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iv1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane1).getConstantState())
```

Comment: +1 for let us know....Is it always work like this ?..I have tried this and is working

Comment: one question on my mind again is that does this load memory for loading images? cause i`m afraid that i might get the error outofmemory error in logcat

Answer (score 2):

`R.drawable.airplane*` is an int, which means you are comparing an ImageView object with an int, which is never true.  Use `iv.getDrawable().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane1));` to compare to Drawable objects.

This is probably not the best option performance wise, you may want to keep track of the index of the displayed image as a class variable, and do a conditional based on that (or something along those lines).

Comment: Hello invertigo i`ve tried what you suggested with this


"if (iv1.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane1)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      
     }"


i`m still getting the wrong toast

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare type of ImageView with the type of int

```
iv1.equals(R.drawable.airplane1)
```

this is wrong

try this

```
iv.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane1)
```

instead

Comment: Hello Pragnani i`ve tried it with this 


"if (iv.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane1)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      
     } else if (iv.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane2)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please put an answer",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else if (iv.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane3)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }"

Comment: now it doesn`t prompt anything at all, i guess i got wrong in my codes

Comment: @NewbieontheSide use setTag and getTag comparision, or setContentDescription and getContentDescription for the imageviews..

Comment: i hvae seen this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view

but i don`t know how to implement it in my code.. sorry i`m new in android/java programming

Comment: In your xml add attribute android:contentDescription="airplane" any name that you can identify..give drawable name for comparision and than compare like this  if(iv.getcontnentDescription.equals("airplace")){//do somehting}

Comment: i`ve tried zabador and it works thanks does that code loads memory on phone for loading images?? cause i`m afraid that i might get outofmemory error in android

Comment: You are using the images in the your drawable folders, Android pick the suitable image for the phone resolution...Not in every where , even in desk top , laptop need ram to show images.. You won't get outofmemory error untill you are using very high resolution images that your phone can't handle

Comment: i`m trying with atleast 10 images, but if i resize the images lower than let`s say 150kb will it be ok??

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `ImageView` instances and `int`s, the right way to check which view was clicked is:

```
if (iv1.getId() == R.id......) { ...
```

this way you are comparing an `int` with another `int`