# Reading files from a custom function is FC the app

Tags: java, android, file, android-listview

I have the following code:

```
        final RelativeLayout mFrame3 =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( R.layout.ptrip, container, false );

        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tc/");
        FilesInFolder = GetFilesData(folder.getAbsolutePath());
        FileSize = GetFileSize(folder.getAbsolutePath());

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> current_file:FilesInFolder.entrySet()) {
            rowsArray.add(new SetRows(R.drawable.ic_launcher, current_file.getKey().toString(), current_file.getValue().toString()));
        }

        adapter = new SetRowsCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.customlist, rowsArray);
    ListView dataList = (ListView) mFrame3.findViewById(R.id.lvFiles);
        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

        dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View 

v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Integer.toString(position), 2000).show();
                // Clicking on items
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), FilesInFolder.get(position).toString() + FileLastModified.get(position).toString() + FileSize.get(position).toString(), 2000).show(); //display filename (0)
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), folder.toString()+ "/" +FilesInFolder.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            /*File flEachFile = new File(folder.toString()+ "/" + FilesInFolder.get(position).toString()); //read POSITION file
            if (!flEachFile.exists()) { //if file does not exist close
                throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
            }
            Log.e("Testing", "Starting to read");
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(flEachFile));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.displayfilecontents);
                dialog.setTitle("Trip Name: " + FilesInFolder.get(position).toString().substring(0, FilesInFolder.get(position).toString().lastIndexOf(".")));

                EditText text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etFileContents);
                if (text != null) {
                    text.setFocusable(false);
                    text.setLongClickable(false);
                    text.setTextIsSelectable(false);
                }
                text.setText(builder);
                Button btnCloseIt = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                btnCloseIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }*/
        }
        });

    public HashMap<String,String> GetFilesData(String DirectoryPath) {
        HashMap<String,String> MyFiles = new HashMap<String,String>();
        File f = new File(DirectoryPath);


        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)  {
                if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".tol")) {
                    long lastTime = files[i].lastModified();
                    String fileName = files[i].getName().substring(0, files[i].getName().lastIndexOf("."));

                    String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(lastTime)).toString();
                    MyFiles.put(fileName, dateString); //Add the new filename and its modification date to the Hasmap
                }
            }
        }

        return MyFiles;
    }
```

The following line is giving an error:

```
File flEachFile = new File(folder.toString()+ "/" + FilesInFolder.get(position).toString());
```

The `FiledInFolder.get(position).toString` worked when the function was when the function only returned the filename only:

```
public ArrayList<String> GetFilesData(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

    //f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)  {
            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".tol")) {
                long lastTime = files[i].lastModified();
                String fileName = files[i].getName().substring(0, files[i].getName().lastIndexOf("."));
                MyFiles.add(fileName); //MyFiles.add(files[i].getName()); if extension is also needed
            }
        }
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
```

The new function returns both the filename and lastmodified date. How do i achieve the same feature with the onClickListener so it works with the new function?

Comment: what is the error? also, what is the method your code is from - getView inside an adapter?

Comment: My app just FC with a NPE and yes it's inside the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GetFileData function is creating a HashMap not an ArrayList. You can not get an element from a HashMap by using its position. Instead individual Hashmap entries are obtained by passing its key (Here is key is filename itself). So you actually need a reference to the hashmap entry. You can use setTag() and getTag() functions of View class to achieve that.

few other alternatives you can try are

1. use findViewbyId

   ```
   dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


   TextView clicked= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_of_textview_that_hold_filename);
   String current_file=clicked.getText().toString();

   }
   ```
2. Try to get filename from rowsArray using position. You may need to use an intermediate final variable to make rowsArray accessible inside listener
3. Make FilesData an ArrayList that holds a string array of size 2.

Inside GetFileData method, create a new string array of size two, store filename and modification date to position 0 & 1. Then add this string array to the array list. You need to change necessary variables from HashMap to ArrayList

Comment: So would using setTag and getTag require the least amount of modification?

Comment: setTag and getTag are meant to be used when you write your own adapter. If you already use a custom adapter, then it should be easy. else it may need a lot of modifications. Have you tried using ArrayList<String[]>

Comment: You alternative #1 worked after some tweaks! Just needed some idea and you provided it. Accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

FilesInFolder is now a Hashmap, so you just want to get the filename at a given position (index), which is the first element of the map - the keys (the 2nd is the timestamp, or values of the map). So you could do something like this:

First convert the map keys to a list:

```
List<Value> filenames = new ArrayList<String>(FilesInFolder.keys());
```

then:

```
File flEachFile = new File(folder.toString()+ "/" + filenames.get(position).toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution. Unfortunately I don't have enough points to HIGH VOTE :/