# unable to disable radio button in listview using arrayadapter

Tags: android

I am developing an application.I have a button to add some users when I click a button it displays a list of radio buttons which are nothing but users(contacts) where I can select multiple users my problem is that I can select any user a select but i cannot deselect the user which is already selected I have used

`buttonView.setEnabled(false);`

this statement but I am unable to deselect can any help me.

I have used arrayadapter to display in list view.
this is the following code

**Main class**

```
public class Contactselectuser extends Activity {
    Contactadapter contactadapteruser;
    private ArrayList<String> listexample;
    Button conform;
    private ListView list;
    ImageButton close;
    boolean check;
    RadioButton rb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectrepresentative);
        conform = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Confirm);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selectrecipientslist);
        listexample=new ArrayList<String>();
        getlist();

        close=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              finish(); 
            }
        });
      contactadapteruser = new Contactadapter(Contactselectuser.this,              
                                    R.layout.selectrepresentative, listexample);
                   list.setAdapter(contactadapteruser);
      private void getlist() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");

        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");

    }

        }
```

**Adapter class**
    New adapter class

```
   public class Contactadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    boolean value;
    ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> listexample;
        public Contactadapter(Context con, int layout, ArrayList<String> listexample) {
            super(con, com.arivoli.amev.R.layout.selectrepresentative, listexample);
            this.context = con;
            this.listexample = listexample;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectradio, parent, false);
                RadioButton rb=(RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
                rb.setText(listexample.get(position));
                value = rb.isChecked();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "status"+value, 5000).show();
                rb.setTag(value);
                rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        RadioButton radio=(RadioButton)v;


                       if(radio.isChecked()){
                           radio.getTag();
                           value = radio.isChecked();
                           radio.setChecked(value);
                           value=false;
                       }else
                       {
                           radio.getTag();
                           radio.setChecked(false);
                            value=true; 
                       }
                       }
                });

                return rowView;


            }


}
```

Comment: why don't you use `CheckBox` ?

Comment: yes we use checkbox but my requirement is radio button

Comment: then use `onClickListner()` instead of `onCheckChangeListener`.

Comment: i have tried onclick but how can i get the status of radiobutton in onclick method to set radio button values.I d'not have parameters to set the radiobutton values

Comment: try as shown in my ans.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to be able to unselect your choices, you should use CheckBox rather that radiobox, and unselect it by using `setSelected(true/false);`

If you want to keep your RadioButtons, try so replace `buttonView.setEnabled(false);` by `buttonView.setChecked(false);`

Comment: I have tried it when do that i am unable to select radio button means it is unchecked but i can get the toast message when click on it

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
 if (value == false) {
```

previously set rb.setTag(value)

and rb.getTag() inside the method and use.

Comment: list view elements are like dynamic views if 20 elements are there in a list and 10 can be shown in screen , so it will hold only those 10 elements and update the 10 elements while user moving the list up or down so inside adapter class having some variable values like position value or some other values will not be respective to that particular element. so if u want a variable inside an adapter class u can use setTag() and get the value using getTag().
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5291891/1937802

Comment: pls tell where should i add rb.setTag(value)

Comment: settag after set the value for the rb and gettag inside the method u r using

Comment: i have used rb.setTag(value); after before rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {} and i have used getTag(); in changeoption method but i am getting error    he method getTag() is undefined for the type new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){}

Comment: get tag is for the item. rb.getTag

Comment: Hey onclick method is working for me thanks but only once how can i make use of setTag and getTag

Comment: good.. and i have given my ans to know about the list view . http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 will give u better understanding about list view accept his ans if works

Comment: i will do that but it is working only once means onclick it will be enable and another click it will disable and if  i click on any item it will not work i have added a comment in ketan can you please read it and tell me where i am wrong

Comment: hm for that only i have suggested as using settag and gettag. it will overcome the list view recycling problems

Comment: hey i will post my new adapter class can you please tell me where should i write the setTag and getTag methods.I have written settag and get tag methods also please help me i want learn android properly

Comment: hey i have added new adapter class pls tell me where i am wrong

Comment: if(radio.isChecked()){ 
replace this with if(rb.getTag){ and try

Comment: it is giving me this error cannot convert from Object to boolean can i write radio.getTag

Comment: it is an obj u have to convert it to boolean 
Boolean.parseBoolean(rb.getTag().toString());

Comment: i have copied the statement Boolean.parseBoolean(rb.getTag().toString()); into if condition  it is giving me  error  Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable rb inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method
 - Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

Comment: make the rb as final and remove that ;

Answer (score 0):

use onClickListner() instead of onCheckChangeListener

```
rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RadioButton radio=(RadioButton)v;

            //do something with radio
            radio.setChecked(value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: value = rb.isEnabled(); i have used this statement before on click method         public void onClick(View v) {
           RadioButton radio=(RadioButton)v;
           //do something with radio
           if(radio.isChecked()){
           radio.setChecked(value);
               value=false;
              }else
              {
               radio.setChecked(value);
                value=true; 
              }
              }
       });                                          thanks buddy its working but i can check and uncheck only once

Comment: heyy help me how should i may value variable as local

Comment: why do you use `setEnabled` and `isEnabled`? Just use `setChecked` and `isChecked`.

Comment: ok but when i scroll down selected radio buttons are unchecked why it is happening

Comment: It happens because of listview recycling. see here [ListView Recycling Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Comment: how to over come it what should i do

Comment: for that please do some google search and then post a new fresh question.

Comment: i have updated my new adapter class can you please check it and tell me where i am going wroung

Answer (score 0):

Below your check i.e radio.isChecked()

YOu have done this :-
`value = radio.isChecked();
  radio.setChecked(value);`

It will set the value the same as it was before.
Shouldn't it be `radio.setChecked(!value);`
This code will deselect if user is selected.