# Android Programmatically adding UI elements at a specific cell

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm using TableLayout. On the click of a Button, I am supposed to hide it and show a progress bar and once the progress bar is done (e.g. downloading a file), I need to hide that and show a different button. The UI gets messed up, if I define these UI elements in the XML layout file. The Progess bar and new button shows as a new column. Any clue how I could dynamically hide and replace a button with progress bar and later a new button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your button use yourButton.setTag(Object) to tag them, later you can find your desired button with findViewByTag(Object) function.

Take a look at this: [What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

For example you can tag every of your buttons with string positionX + "," + positionY

Answer (score 0):

Android allows the use of a setVisibility method call on Views.

- Set up the xml where you want it, you are actually able to put things
  on top of each other but i wouldn't recommmend it.
- In your onCreate() method ensure that the fields/Buttons/Views are
  allcreated but then set the visibility to
  setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); followed by setEnabled(false);
- Once you have figured out your UI flow (the actual progression
  through the process), determine where each view/button/field are to
  be displayed or hidden and code in    where this needs to happen.
- To ensure that the flow works, and reduce the chance of a user
  entering a state in-which your views are loading in at the wrong time,
  create boolean variables and maybe getters and setters to create
  logic rules that are applicable.
- setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) are what you are looking for.