# Declaring variables outside onCreate - Android

Tags: java, android

My application stops when I declare the TextView outside the onCreate method, I'm doing this because I need do access the TextView variable from other methods as well. I'll be grateful for any kind of help.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.defaultText);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just define your TextView as a class scoped variable (ie, place it at the top of your class outside of any method scope.

Comment: Look in Logcat for the actual error message.  When you ask a question like this, include the Logcat info with your question.

Comment: @Dale the answer is clear when reading the code.

Comment: @TehCoder  True, but if the OP had looked at Logcat he wouldn't have needed to ask the question, and this question is not likely to help future SO users.

Answer (score 4):

```
My application stops when I declare the TextView outside the onCreate method
```

That is because the Layout is not yet inflated in your activity thus crashing you app and I am **100% sure** the error is `NPE` when you set the text here : `textView.setText("Hello");`.

**Solution:**

always initialized your `TextView` inside your `Oncreate` after `setContentView` and having your `textView` object as a global instance.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.defaultText);
        textView.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare a View outside a function.

`TextView tv;`
and in OnCreate do:
`tv = (TextView)findViewById(...)`

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the error you are getting is because the view containing the TextView as a child as not yet been inflated. You should declare the strong reference and then instantiate the variable on the onCreate() method. If you insist on using such a code then I recommend you to take a look at Dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.defaultText);
```

You first set the **content view** to the `Activity` if not will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem and i solved it by using (tag) for my view (`myTextView.tag`)
you can lean more about this property from here:

[What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

I mean I declare a variable called (counter) outside `onCreate` method, then i find my view wherever i need using his tag.

hope this helping