# What is the working of setTag and getTag in ViewHolder pattern?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have a simple code snippet for implementing custom listview.

My code is as follows:

**WeatherAdapter.java :**

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<weather>{

    Context mcontext; 
    int mlayoutResourceId;    
   weather mdata[] = null;
   View row;

    public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, weather[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        mlayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       mcontext = context;
        mdata = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ( (Activity) mcontext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(mlayoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder(row);


            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        weather w = mdata[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(w.mtitle);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(w.micon);

        return row;
    }
```

**WeatherHolder.java**:

```
class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;


    public WeatherHolder(View v){

          imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
          txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    }
    }
}
```

I have seen so many answers on SO and other sites and I understood the recycling mechanism of listview.

I also understood that from viewholder, we can hold the child views in the adapter and we do not have to call `findViewById()` many times. So, it is for optimization.

But I have only the confusion in `setTag(holder)` and `getTag()` methods. [From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view), I came to know that it is for making a key-value pair on multiple objects, so that we can access them easily. But, I do not understand why they are required here...because, we do not have multiple holder objects...only we have to change holder's variables each time. can we code here without using `setTag` and `getTag`?

can anyone explain better that what `setTag` and `getTag` do "here"?

Comment: please do not mark as duplicate...I have seen so many answers but couldn't find the right for particular situation.

Comment: why not try it your way and see what the outcome is?

Comment: I have already tried...I have not asked question without any try..If  you know, then please give the answer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`tag` is a mechanism to make your `views` remember something, that could be an `object` an `integer` a `string` or anything you like.

so when your `ListView` is going to create for the first time your `convertView` is `null`. so you create a new `convertView` and put all of your `references` of the `objects` of that `row` in a `viewHolder`. then save your `viewHolder` into the memory of that `convertView`(**setTag**). `Android` takes your `convertView` and puts it in its `pool` to `recycle` it and `passes` it again to you. but its `pool` may not have enough `convertViews` so it again passes a new `convertView` thats `null`. so again the story is repeated till the `pool` of `android` is filled up. after that `android` takes a `convertView` from its pool and passes it to you. you will find that its not `null` so you ask it where are my object `references` that I gave to you for the first time? (**getTag**) so you will get those and do whatever you like.

**More elaboration on below line**

`but its pool may not have enough convertViews so it again passes a new convertView thats null`

android `pool` is empty when your `listView` is going to create. so for the first item of your `listView` it sends you a `convertView` that must be displayed. after that `android` saves it in its `pool`, so its `pool` now contains just one `convertView`. for your second item of your `listView` that is going to create android can not use its pool because it is actually has one element and that element is your first item and it is being shown right now so it has to pass another `convertView`. this process repeates until `android` found a `convertView` in its `pool` thats not being displayed now and passes it to you.

Android inflates each row till the screen filled up after that when you scroll the list it uses holder.

Comment: thanks but I coudn't understand this: "but its pool may not have enough convertViews so it again passes a new convertView thats null" - then in which situation,it may not have enough convertviews?

Comment: thanks...In short, Android have to inflate the new row's layout until the layout fits the screen size. after than it uses the holder to change the child views within the row. right?

Answer (score 18):

Lets Look in a Different Perspective:

[image]

Lets imagine that the *Helicopter* is the "**row**" while the *rope* is the "**setTag**" and the *car* below is "**WeatherHolder**", but the pilot of the Helicopter is inside that car and he/she the one managing controlling the helicopter using a "WIRED REMOTE".

When you cut the Rope Which is "setTag" the Hellicopter still fly but the pilot can no longer control it since the pilot is drop in the ground which means the pilot is now dead! (In java when an object loss its reference the Garbage Collector will collect that and free from the memory).

When you did not place or attach the rope to the car while the Helicopter is about to fly where the Pilot is sitting - you potentially loss a control on the helicopter because you are using "WIRED REMOTE".

I hope this help :).

Answer (score 2):

> But, I do not understand why they are required here...because, we do not have multiple holder objects

This is where you are wrong - there is one holder per view (aka visible or cached ListView entry).

Comment: can you explain in more detail?

Comment: There's a separate `WeatherHolder holder` for each view.

Comment: @ShivamVerma right.  but  holder = new WeatherHolder(row); is called only for first time inflation. (when converview is null - or when no layout is inflated)

Comment: It is called for first time inflation per view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61647/discussion-between-xyz-and-shivam-verma).