# Save some information in Android's tag

Tags: android

I want to know if it is good practice to save some metadata to the View's tag.
I have this code:

```
TableRow file = new TableRow(getActivity());
file.setTag(<Object_with_data>);
```

And in the OnClickListener:

```
file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Object_with_data instanse1 = 
                    (Object_with_data) view.getTag();
        }
});
```

Comment: It's a question about "best practice" :)

Comment: Basically that's fine. I wouldn't make those objects to complex though, usually it's just an identifier, like a String or Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think it is a good practice. According to the official doc :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

> A tag can be used to mark a view in its hierarchy and does not have to
>   be unique within the hierarchy. Tags can also be used to store data
>   within a view without resorting to another data structure.

and another question on StackOverflow :

[What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

> It's basically a way for views to have memories.

The View's tag seems to be created to allows you to actually store metadata.