# Set and get unique parameter in image button android

Tags: java, android

I am loading list view by listview adapter class.
Within that list view I have button called favorite.

```
ImageButton mFavorite = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.method_fav_btn);
```

There are multiple image buttons under the same id. I want to identify which button was pressed by means of setting some extra parameters to it. I am doing this for that:

```
mFavorite.setId(pm.getId());
```

And on click:

```
mFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Id is: "+mFavorite.getId());
    }
});
```

But, the problem is, I have 3 items in list view. Every time I am getting same id. How to get different ids on different clicks?
Thanks.

Comment: Use `v.getUd()` instead of `mFavourite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setTag()` + `getTag()` methods.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view) for a similar question and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) for the official documentation.

Comment: I tried it. Still I am getting same value each time.

Comment: You are probably recreating the image button on every call. Are you using a viewholder to cahce the views?

Comment: oh... actually, I got it. I was trying to do `mFavorite.getTag()` instead of `v.getTag()`;