# User option of an element

Tags: android

How can i set my own option on view? 
I need something like this:

```
TableRow tblr_data = new TableRow(this);
tblr_data.setOption("my_option", "my_option_value"); //there is no such method
```

Another words i need to add custom option to table row (custom id for example) and then use it in onclick handler.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you expand on it?

Comment: Yet I still have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use the setTag(int key, Object tag) method.

```
//member variable
private int MY_OPTION = 1;

//when creating your tablerow
tblr_data.setTag(MY_OPTION, "my_option_value");
```

then in your onClickListener, you can just fetch that value again by calling

```
String value = (String)tblr_data.getTag(MY_OPTION);
```

See this accepted answer for more on the get/setTag() method.

[What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)