# Android call onActivityResult upon listview selection

Tags: java, android, listview, onactivityresult

I was having some problem when I try to get the selected row from list view to do something upon the button onClickListener.

Basically I have a button for each listview row. When the button is selected, it will navigate to QR code scan intent. When the result returned at the onActivityResult(), I wanted to do something with that row. This is how I set up the button listener:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendee_listview_row,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txt_dName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayName);
                            viewHolder.btn_scan = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_dName.setText(attendeeList.get(position)
                .getAccountName().trim());

        viewHolder.btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
```

And here is the onActivityResult():

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            if(attendeeName.equals("Andrew") && contents.equals("QRCode1")){

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Event QR code does not match.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
```

I already made an if else statement inside the onActivityResult but I not sure how to get the selected row previously.

Any guides?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATES

Here is the llist view row item xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnScan"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/qr_icon" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplayName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/lightred"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRegisteredTag"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        anddroid:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/registered" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So basically I have a registered image for each row. Then inside the if statement, let's say the conditons are matched, how do I should the registered image for that row?

Answer (score 0):

How long is your list? If it doesn't contain too many items, you could use a switch statement on the request code. In your `Adapter` you can pass the position as the request code to `startActivityForResult();`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendee_listview_row,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txt_dName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayName);
                            viewHolder.btn_scan = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txt_dName.setText(attendeeList.get(position)
                .getAccountName().trim());

        viewHolder.btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, position);
            }
        });
```

and in onActivityResult():

```
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {

    switch(requestCode){
        case 0:
        // == first list item
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                if(attendeeName.equals("Andrew") && contents.equals("QRCode1")){

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Event QR code does not match.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            }
            break;
        case 1:
        // = second list item
        .
        .
        .
        default:
            break;
    }   

}
```

Kind of a hack, but it should work.

Comment: It shouldn't be too long cause my current data set still not much data. Would you mind to provide me some example?

Comment: Let's say case 0 and I wanted to highlight the background of the row. Am I still able to do that?

Comment: Yes, that should be no problem. You just have to clear your lists adapter and fill you list again, after you've highlighted the item 0 in your list.

Comment: Sorry but would you mind to provide me a solution? Cause from what I've found, they used the convertView inside the getView() to highlight the row. But I not sure how I do this from onActivityResult()

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what your lists data looks like and where it comes from. You could use a custom class for you data with a `boolean isHighlighted`. In `onActivityResult();` you can set the boolean to true and update your list. But this is just one of many ways how you could achieve this.

Comment: That update doesn't really help. Or are you asking how to highlight you layout?

Answer (score 0):

For each row of the list you sets the tag. You have to set `android:onClick` in your xml buttons and when you define the handlers you can take the tags as objects.
Define one object `TextView` where you will save the tag using `getTag()` from the view V.

```
TextView tv = v.getTag();
```

Sorry for my english. Anyway this url may helps you [What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

Comment: Sorry but I do not get it. Would you mind for futher explanation or provide me with some code example?

Comment: This example helped me to learn how to use atributes from each item of the listviews [link]https://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/listview-item-with-button/