# Attaching custom data (string tag) to a MATLAB cfit object

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, subclassing, undocumented-behavior

I have a code where [`cfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cfit.html) objects are passed back and forth between functions\classes and I would like to have a ["tag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view) that contains some information about my fit (i.e. its name), such that I instantiate it at some point and can access it later whenever it's needed.

Ideally, this would be right inside the object, so that whenever I need to access the information, it's available without the need to drag around (or in `appdata`) additional vectors\cells.

#### Attempts & Thoughts

Normally, one would simply subclass `cfit` and add a property that contains this data. However, the declaration of `cfit` (see below) tells us that it is `Sealed`, and therefore cannot be subclassed.

```
classdef (Sealed = true) cfit < fittype
```

Alternatively, we could try to "hijack" some property that is not used by the current objects and use *it* to store the required data ([not that it's a technical problem](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-private-object-properties), but this is equivalent to ignoring the developers' warnings that these properties shouldn't be touched).

Moreover, from the above `classdef` we also learn that this is a subclass of `fittype` which may have some properties\methods we could use for this purpose.

Finally, **the question** remains - what is the best place to save my additional bit of data, so that it is both convenient to set\get (*convenient* means that if I want to access it inside a loop, I don't have to use [`eval()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html)), and doesn't interfere with the normal operation of `cfit` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that seems to work is by accessing the `.p` structure of a `cfit` object and adding whatever to it:

Before:

```
>> F378

F378 = 

     Shape-preserving (pchip) interpolant:
       F378(x) = piecewise polynomial computed from p
     Coefficients:
       p = coefficient structure

>> F378.p

ans = 

      form: 'pp'
    breaks: [1x40 double]
     coefs: [39x4 double]
    pieces: 39
     order: 4
       dim: 1
```

After `F378.p.tag = '3.78';`:

```
F378.p

ans = 

  form: 'pp'
breaks: [1x40 double]
 coefs: [39x4 double]
pieces: 39
 order: 4
   dim: 1
   tag: '3.78'
```

I found this from the following error:

```
Error using cfit/subsref (line 18)
The name 'probnames' is not a coefficient or a problem parameter. You can only use dot 
notation to access the coefficients and problem parameters of a cfit or sfit, for example 
'f.p'.

For the current object the properties you can access like this are:

p
```

**Caution is advised:** I did not test whether this solution interferes with normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than subclass `cfit`, make a new class and store the `cfit` object as a property, along with your tag as another property.

Comment: So you're basically suggesting a wrapper class for `cfit` (or a box\unbox pattern). This is an interesting idea - what worries me is that this solution is a bit dangerous with regard to [type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) (which MATLAB disregards anyway most of the time), and hence compatibility, since in the rest of the codebase objects are assumed to be `cfit`s - and so inherited fittype\cfit functions will not be "exposed" anymore unless "pipelined" separately.

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting you just use the class as a thin wrapper around cfit, to enable you to collect it together with your tag - barely more functionality than a struct with a cfit as one field and the tag as another, just a bit more formalised. You'd only have to modify your code to use myobject.mycfitprop rather than the original cfit.

Comment: Also, I suggest submitting an enhancement request to MathWorks, asking them to stop sealing all their classes- I find it kind of antisocial.