# xamarin android creating dynamic button with id

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am developing android application using xamrin and C#
I am stuck when I create multiple buttons dynamically and assign them id.
When I click on the button I get same id for all the Button.
Any one can tell me how to create button with id so each button can be identified using id at runtime.

```
btnViewSupplier = new Button(this);
                            btnViewSupplier.Text =Convert.ToString(supplierInformationList[i]);
                            btnViewSupplier.Gravity= GravityFlags.Left;
                            btnViewSupplier.TextSize =18;
                            btnViewSupplier.ScrollBarSize = 20;
                            btnViewSupplier.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#29abe2"));
                            btnViewSupplier.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                            btnViewSupplier.Id=supplierID[i];

        public void callToview()
        {
            AppCode.ProfileId = Convert.ToInt32(btnViewSupplier.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("viewclicked");
            StartActivity(typeof(SupplierView));
        }
```

Comment: after doing your tests, please consider to choose the answer that best fits with your purposes. thank you

Comment: We need the full code. It looks like you're creating your buttons in a loop with the index `i` using the list `supplierID`. Are you sure this list has different numbers and your loop is working properly? We cannot see that from your code.

Comment: I was able to figure out. I had given reference of button out side of the method. so, just have to give reference Button btnViewsupplier; before crating instance of button. and it worked any ways thanks for replying me

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating random number and assigning it to `ID` property of button like this:

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        int id = rand.Next(1000000000, 999999999);
```

To avoid duplicates you can put generated ids in collection and after `rand.Next` call check if number is already generated.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your question, I'd go for using tags instead of id(s): Android lets you tag any view with anything you like (even custom objects) so you can recognize elements as you were working with id(s).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291891/2003114) you find a good example of tag usage.

Hope this can help :)