# how to set value for each item button increase and decrease click and set that value in text view

Tags: android

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] result;
    int[] imageId;
    String[] Cost;
    static int counter = 0;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    public MyCustomAdapter(Context mainActivity, String[] result, int[] imageId, String[] Cost
    ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.result = result;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.Cost = Cost;
        this.context = mainActivity;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView tv;
        TextView cost;
        ImageView img;
        ImageView plusitem;
        ImageView minusitem;
        TextView itemnumber;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.cost = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.plusitem = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        holder.minusitem = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        holder.itemnumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        holder.plusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                holder.itemnumber.setText(String.valueOf( _counter));
                //holder.itemnumber.setText(result[position]);

            }
        });

        holder.minusitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.itemnumber.setText(String.valueOf( _counter));
                //  holder.itemnumber.setText(result[position]);
            }
        });


        return rowView;

    }}
```

This is my adapter we have +button for increase item and - button 
for decrease item i have to  get item number  like in first item 
if we have 2 item and second item  we can 3 ,4 .. so on.. 
actuality i want to add item on cart  actually i 
have tried with static variable its not working Properly 
[image]please tell me logic . look my screen below

Answer (score 2):

Create the `Buttons` and the `TextView` as shown in your design.Write `onclick` methods for the `Buttons`.Initialize an `Integer` variable for saving the count.In the click of + button,increment the count by one and set the text in `Textview`.Similarly,when you click the - button,decrement the count by one and set the text in your `TextView`.

```
  int count=0;
    TextView txtCount =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Button buttonInc= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button buttonDec= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    buttonInc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));

        }
    });

buttonDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count--;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));

        }
    });
```

Comment: That i have apply But here Problem as i tell u Suppose in item i have set item with 5 now suppose i increase item 2 then it start from six while it should Start from 1

Comment: Use `ViewHolder` in your Adapter class and set the value as your `TextView ` using setTag() method.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/XDjKU6345XaHBbTbTVb43M  look my code i have done same thing

Comment: use setTag() because you can save the value to the textView itself. Refer  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view

Comment: view.setTag(result[position],_counter);   like this we ll have to Increase?

Comment: will please tell me some more

Comment: Set tag like **txtCount.setTag(count);** on button clicks. Retrieve tag value as **txtCount.getTag()** and save value to a string and set the text of textview to the value you got.

Comment: holder.itemnumber.setTag(_counter);
                holder.itemnumber.getTag();
 I am using this code but still its not working i am unable to print please suggest me how to set and get value for each item

Comment: I told you to retrieve the value using getTag() and save it in a string and set it to TextView.Did you do that?

Comment: yes u look on item click  holder.minusitem.setOnClickListener

Comment: I see this `holder.itemnumber.setTag(_counter);
                holder.itemnumber.getTag();

                //  holder.itemnumber.setText(result[position]);` which is not what i said.Where is the code for setting the count here?

Comment: count++ and count-- look that

Comment: Use this .`String count = String.valueOf(holder.itemnumber.getTag());` and `holder.itemnumber.setText(count);`

Comment: but ho will increase and decrease value if  we ll Put ur code  i want incrrease on +button icon and decrease - button icon for each item i want do this seprtly

Answer (score 2):

```
 holder.cart_minus_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

//1. List item

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.cart_product_quantity_tv.getText()));

            if(count>0){

 //2. enter code here

                count--;

                holder.cart_product_quantity_tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            }
        }
    });

    holder.cart_plus_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.cart_product_quantity_tv.getText()));
            count++;
            holder.cart_product_quantity_tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash map.For every item clicked store the item id as the key and the clicked count as the value.

For eg:`<Item_id:item_count>`

This way you can easily manage the user's selection and also its more efficient than using static variables as you need to have only a single hashmap .

Comment: what value we ll put item id

Comment: You each item is unique I believe,so put that id as the item id.

Comment: same issue am facing when i try to get value from another item it increase or decrese according to previsou item value

Comment: why are u using position to set the item number?.2 items can have the same position when u scroll.U should have a unique identifier for individual items

Comment: what i have to set please look my code and tell me how to set coz i have used ur logic

Comment: What data u have for your item that is clicked ..like name ,id  etc?
instead of this  hm.put(result[position].toString(), String.valueOf(_counter)); put  hm.put(<an id representing that item>, String.valueOf(_counter));

Comment: we have Product name and Qunatity

Comment: if that product name is unique then use that as the key

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should maintain one arraylist of custom class having fields like ItemId, ItemName, Price, Quantity, Image and so on. So that you can easily maintain quantity and other details in shopping cart.

Now in adapter you just need to pass this arrayList, no need of passing different Arrays.

```html
int quantity = arraylist.get(position).getItemQuantity();

btnIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            quantity++;
            tvQuantity.setText(quantity+"");

        }
    });

btnDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            quantity--;
            tvQuantity.setText(quantity+"");

        }
    });
```

This works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

This is the Adapter add to cart in this you can see on btnIncrease and btnDecrease in that i change the value of cart and i use notifyDataSetChanged(); it will change the data automatically

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Movie> moviesList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, cart, genre;
        public Button btnIncrease,btnDecrease;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            cart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart);
            btnIncrease =view.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            btnDecrease = view.findViewById(R.id.minus);

        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.cart.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getcart()));
        holder.btnIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                movie.cart++;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.btnDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (movie.cart>0)
                     movie.cart--;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```