# How do I access a textview or progressbar in relative layout programatically when multiple?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, programmatically-created

I am creating multiple relative layouts in an activity, programmatically.   Each is identical and has a textview as well as a ProgressBar spinner.

I want to programmatically change them when needed but not sure how to access the appropriate one.   I believe I need to add a unique SetId() to each item (or maybe the relativelayout itself) but not sure the best way to do so.

I also am not sure if I use findViewById to access the views once created to make the changes (SetText,  SetVisibility, etc).

Here is the code

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvpName = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvpName.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pbpSpinner = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pbpSpinner.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    pbpSpinner.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        RelativeLayout acctrl = new RelativeLayout(this);

        TextView tvName = new TextView(this);

        ProgressBar pbSpinner = new ProgressBar(this);
        pbSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Add items to Account Interal Layout
        acctrl.addView(tvName, tvpName);
        acctrl.addView(pbSpinner, pbpSpinner);
 }
```

Any recommendations / suggestions?

Comment: Why not create an array of `RelativeLayout`s and just store them in the array as they are created? Then you will have a reference to each one.

Comment: Guess I am not sure how to do an array of RelativeLayouts and then reference the views within them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `View` programatically, it's a good practice to `setId()`. Additionally, you can go ahead and `setTag()` also. By setting a `Tag`, you can know what each `RelativeLayout` or any other view. This way you can get a hold of the view that you are looking for.

If you are not going to access or modify the `RelativeLayout` then you need not set ID for it, but setting an id for it makes this easier, so that you can just send the ID of the `RelativeLayout` as a parameter to a method and it will perform all operations on the `Views` it holds, since you said all `RelativeLayout`s are identical.

If you are using `setId()`, then you can use the `findViewById()` to get the view. 
If you are using `setTag()`, the you can refer this on how to use it to get the view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291891/4747587

Comment: As mentioned, I thought I had to `setId()`... but do I set it on the `RelativeLayout` or the views in the `RelativeLayout`?  Once set, whats the best way, programmatically to access those Views... `findViewById`?

Comment: You should `setId(int)` on the `RelativeLayout`s and the inner `View`s. Then you can just call `findViewById(int)` with the int used in `setId` and you will get a reference to the `View` whether it be one of your layouts or inner views.