# button click on listview displays the same output

Tags: java, android

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.joinlistviewitem, parent, false);
    resultp = data.get(position);
    name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.personname);
    name.setText(resultp.get(Joinlistview.RANK));   
    Button deletejoin=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    deletejoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //resultp.get("userId");            
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("delete clicked", "delete clicked");
            Toast.makeText(context,"clicked"+resultp.get(Joinlistview.RANK), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        }
    });

    return itemView;
}
```

I used the above code for button click on listview.If i click a button it sows the user name with its position. But it displays the same name in all position.??How to solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getTag/setTag` methods for getting current row value inside `onClick` as:

```
Button deletejoin=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
deletejoin.setTag(resultp.get(Joinlistview.RANK));
```

And on Button Click:

```
Toast.makeText(context,"clicked "+ v.getTag().toString(),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Joinlistview is a class and am accesing the string from that class..But it displays the name in the list correctly.when i click button it displays the same name

Comment: @Prasanna: See my answer

Comment: @prosper Thanks for the answer. can u pls explain about this"deletejoin.setTag(resultp.get(Joinlistview.RANK));"?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K   Thanks for the answer. can u pls explain about this"deletejoin.setTag(resultp.get(Joinlistview.RANK));"?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I was the downvote because your initial answer was wrong. I've retracted it. Your current answer is how it should be done, and I've deleted my shortcut answer.

Comment: @Prasanna: See following post for more details [What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)