# How to start multiple activity By onClick method

Tags: android, android-button

I am working on a project where I am showing multiple image in SwipeView with a button. So whenever the button is clicked a new activity will start according to the position of the image in the array. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each item in your list, you need a `Class` reference on which Activity you want to start, then assign the click listener to pass that `Class` to an `Intent` and then `startActivity`

Assuming you have some `ArrayList<Class> list` or an `ArrayAdapter<SomeObject> adapter`, you could do

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Class activityClass = list.get(clickPosition);
    // Class activityClass = adapter.getItem(clickPosition).getActivityToStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You could also use a String tag on the View with the name of a class, but you'll need to catch the `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String className = (String) v.getTag();
    Class activityClass = Class.forName(className);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How to set for  private int []imgID ={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3};

Comment: Either make a custom class with a constructor like `MyObject(R.drawable.img1, Activity1.class)` and put those in an `ArrayList<MyObject>` or have a `private Class[] classes = {Activity1.class, ...}` of the same length

Answer (score 0):

Set a tag (relevant to the activity being launched) to each `ImageView` while inflating, using `setTag` method.

In the onClick handler retrive the tag using the `getTag` method. Use this information to launch the required activity, using a simple `switch case` .

The tag can be anything like activity name, array index etc.

More info: [What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

Comment: what parameter will I use for the switch case Switch(view .Param)?