# Get id of selected item in Spinner from SQLite and add id value to a SQLite Table

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

I am a newcomer to Android Programming. I am trying to populate a Spinner with `league_names` from the `leagues` table from an SQLite Database. I want to then pass the value of the `id` of the selected item in the spinner to another method `addTeam` that adds that value to into a column in another table. Currently I have been able to view the `league_names` in the spinner but I am unsure how get the `id` of the selected item. I have been able to set the items as the id value i.e `1,2,3,4` and pass that value to the `addTeam` method but the user would not know which league they are selecting.

### leagues Table example:

```
id   | league_names
--------------------
 1   | Division 1
 2   | Division 2
 3   | Premier League
 4   | UK League
```

Below is my code:

```
public class add_team extends AppCompatActivity {

 //Calls DatabaseHelper Class
 DatabaseHelper myDb;

 EditText team_name, image;
 Button add_team, get_teams;
 Spinner league;

 ArrayList < String > leagues = new ArrayList < String > ();
 ArrayAdapter < String > adapter;

 int leagueIdParse = 0;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.add_team);

  myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

  team_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_team_name);
  image = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_image);

  add_team = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insertTeams);
  get_teams = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_teams);

  league = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_league_id);

  adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, leagues);

  addTeam();

  if (leagues == null) {
   leagues = new ArrayList < String > ();
  }
  leagues.clear();
  Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllLeagues();

  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   //Extract the data
   int leagueId = cursor.getInt(0);
   String leagueName = cursor.getString(1);

   leagues.add(leagueName);
  }

  league.setAdapter(adapter);

  league.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    try {
     leagueIdParse = Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
     System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
    }


   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent) {

   }
  });

 }

 public void addTeam() {
  add_team.setOnClickListener(
   new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Team team = new Team();
     team.setTeamName(team_name.getText().toString());
     team.setPath(image.getText().toString());
     team.setLeague_id(leagueIdParse);
     myDb.createTeam(team);

    }
   }
  );
 }

}
```

### getAllLeagues method

```
public Cursor getAllLeagues() {
 //Create SQLiteDatabase instance
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

 String[] columns = {
  ID,
  LEAGUE_NAME
 };

 //Return query to return cursor object
 return db.query(LEAGUES_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: no, no, no, do not use `ArrayAdapter` or any custom one, use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead, and when inside `onItemSelected` use the last parameter or even better just use `league.getSelectedItemId()` in `addTeam`

Answer (score 0):

For this you need a custom adapter for populating spinner ... in android there is a `setTag(...)` option . you can set the id with associated leage name and in your item onclick event you can easily get the id form getTag method..

[custom spinner](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84),

[use of setTag(),getTag()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

or there is another option after getting the selected text you need to hit again database for retrieving corresponding id... but i think this is not a good idea.