# How to make each input in edit text a value in an array in android?

Tags: android, arrays

I am making a grading app, basically I have an edit field (number field) that you can enter your grades (in numbers) in, or multiple fields for each grade? But lets say I want to calculate the average grade , and if my edit fields are not in an array I would have to go through each value of the field by id and that is going to make the code too long. So I want an array that takes values from each edit field, so if I have 2 edit fields and I type 4 in the first and 6 in the second my array would be {4,6}. I am a beginner in android development but I have solid Java experience.

Comment: One possibility is to add a button next to each EditText where you catch the onClick and inside the onClickListener you put the editText.getText().ToString() value inside your ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

There's only so much you can do here since each EditText is its own object with its own value field. So to some extent, you're going to have to reference each EditText.

What you can do at least is track each EditText in a List as a member variable. that way you're only having to grab a reference to each edittext once in your activity. Then, when you need to reference the collection for averaging or whatever else, you can just iterate over the list calling .getText(). If you need to reference a specific edittext, either store a separate reference in another member variable, or look it up in the list by id or by a tag you set (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view) for more info on tags).

Comment: Lets say I got an input of 1445 , and I know how to make an array {1,4,4,5} but that is only the case when that input is in a single EditText so is there a way I can put automatic spacing between the numbers so it wont be when i type it 1445 but it would be 1 4 4 5? And maybe the only input you can type is 1,2,3,4 or 5? That would make it alot more visually better. Btw thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe init each editText in a HashMap with a list of numeric values and use the editText reference to add and get values to the list of numeric values like this:

```
final Map<EditText, List<Integer>> editTexts = HashMap<EditText, List<Integer>>();
```

If you init an EditText you could do something like this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editTexts.put(editText , new ArrayList<>());

editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        editTexts.get((EditText) v).add(SOME_VALUE);
    }
);
```

I havn't tested it but this could be a valid strategy.