# create Button likes similar to social media platforms

Tags: android

It seems a really common and stupid question , but I didn't how to search it in  [google](https://www.google.com.lb/#q=android+button+like). I want to make a like button the same exists in social media platforms. I have 3 images in a gridview for 3 users , user1,user2 and user3. If I clicked on like button of user2 how to know that it belong to user 2 and increase the likes of this user?

Comment: use setTag()  and getTag() for each button

Comment: @Mehta do you know a tutorial link or SO answer?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5291891/4628611