# Android - Using getTag and setTag in custom adapter Recyclerview

Tags: android, tags

I am curious about custom Adapter of RecyclerView. Does the adapter need to use setTag() and getTag()for performance?
I read some articles and it points that using Tag is better because it will get data return from setTag() in getTag(). 
Does anyone execute the test about this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view

Comment: This doesn't relate to my question. I am going to find out with RecyclerView