# Printing out a Variable Name in a Toast

Tags: java, android

I am current working through a SeekBar example located [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-seekbar-example). This example has one seek bar, but I wanted to see what would happen if I added two more seek bars.

While the listeners all seem to still work, I want to add the name of the SeekBar to the toast that shows up while tracking the the touch bar. However, I can't just add the name of the variable to the toast ( the passed in seekBar is a widget ) and this doesn't fit the function call of toString().

How would I add the name of the seekBar that I'm focusing on to the Toast?

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.javatpoint.seekbar;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.widget.SeekBar;  
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{  
    SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2, seekBar3;
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

      seekBar1=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);  
      seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
      seekBar2=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
      seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
      seekBar3=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
      seekBar3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}  
@Override  
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,  
        boolean fromUser) {
    //This is where I want to print out the variable name
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seekbar progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}  
@Override  
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),seekBar +"seekbar touch started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}  
@Override  
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}  
@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  
    return true;  
 }  
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekBar1"/>
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekBar2"/>
```

Comment: Note that variable names are typically only available at compile-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted a link to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view/5291891#5291891) last night detailing the use of tags to solve my problem, but unfortunately they either removed their post or it was deleted before I could mark it as the correct answer.

I was able to use the info in that post to set a string as the tag for each seekBar, and then pass that into a new function that took the tag as well as the progress from the seekbar to show different toasts for each seekbar.
Here was the final version of the MainActivity

```
package com.javatpoint.seekbar;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.widget.SeekBar;  
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{  
SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2, seekBar3;
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    seekBar1=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);  
    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekBar1.setTag("1");
    seekBar2=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekBar2.setTag("2");
    seekBar3=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
    seekBar3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekBar3.setTag("3");
}  
@Override  
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,  
        boolean fromUser) {
    changeValue(seekBar.getTag(), progress);
}  
@Override  
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}  
@Override  
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}  
@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  
    return true;  
}
public void changeValue(Object a, int progress){
    if(a=="1"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seekbar1 progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(a=="2"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seekbar2 progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(a=="3"){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seekbar3 progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}