# Android Studio - Help me to understand this code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout-inflater, android-viewholder

Im trying to understand this code:

```
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName, txtSinger;
    ImageView playB, stopB;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (view == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        // inflate (create) another copy of our custom layout
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);


        viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songName_text);
        viewHolder.txtSinger = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.singer_text);
        viewHolder.playB = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.play_png);
        viewHolder.stopB = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.stop_png);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    final Song song = arrayList.get(position);

    // make changes to our custom layout and its subviews
    viewHolder.txtName.setText(song.getName());
    viewHolder.txtSinger.setText(song.getSinger());

    // play music
    viewHolder.playB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // MediaPlayer has not been initialized OR clicked song is not the currently loaded song
            if (currentSong == null || song != currentSong) {

                // Sets the currently loaded song
                currentSong = song;
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, song.getSong());

                Toast.makeText(context, "Playing: "+ song.getSinger() + " " + song.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                viewHolder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                viewHolder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }
        }
    });

    // stop
    viewHolder.stopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // If currently loaded song is set the MediaPlayer must be initialized
            if (currentSong != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                currentSong = null; // Set back currently loaded song
            }
            viewHolder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

But not the whole code!
The part that is confusing me is the `ViewHolder` part.

**My questions:**

- Why do i have to create a `private class` called `ViewHolder` instead
  of just creating a `public method` to store all my views (`txtName,
  txtSinger, playB, stopB`) and use that in my `inflater`?
- what does `view.setTag(viewHolder)` means?
- What is exactly `setTag` and `getTag` in this context?

If anyone can break this down for me it would be very helpful to progress my understanding of code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is exactly setTag and getTag in this context?

Android views support "tags", which are arbitrary objects you can attach to them. There's no real definition for tags, because they're whatever you want them to be. All of these are equally valid:

- `view.setTag(2)`
- `view.setTag("Hello world")`
- `view.setTag(new Object())`

> what does view.setTag(viewHolder) means?

You're attaching the `viewHolder` object to `view` as its tag. This doesn't *do* anything by itself, but it lets you retrieve the `viewHolder` later on by calling `(ViewHolder) view.getTag()`.

> Why do i have to create a private class called ViewHolder [...]

When you're working with `ListView` adapters, there are two things that can slow the performance of your app way down: calling `inflate()` and calling `findViewById()`.

You get around the first by using the passed-in `view` argument when it's not null, and only calling `inflate()` when the passed in `view` argument is null. That's this bit of your code:

> ```
> if (view == null) {
>     ...
>     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>     view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);
>     ...
> } else {
>     ...
> }
> ```

You get around the second by using this "ViewHolder pattern". You create an **object** (the view holder) to "hold" the views after you look them up. That's this bit of your code:

> ```
> final ViewHolder viewHolder;
> if (view == null) {
>     viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
>     ...
>     viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songName_text);
>     viewHolder.txtSinger = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.singer_text);
>     viewHolder.playB = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.play_png);
>     viewHolder.stopB = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.stop_png);
>     view.setTag(viewHolder);
> } else {
>     viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
> }
> ```

Once that block is done, you'll have a `ViewHolder` instance named `viewHolder` that you can use to access views directly. When the passed-in `view` argument is null, you *create* the view holder, *populate* it by calling `findViewById()`, and *save* it by calling `setTag()`. When the passed-in `view` argument is not null, you can simply *retrieve* the view holder by calling `getTag()`.

Put that all together, and that means you can write code like this:

> ```
> viewHolder.txtName.setText(song.getName());
> ```

Instead of this slower code:

```
TextView txtName = view.findViewById(R.id.songName_text);
txtName.setText(song.getName());
```

Comment: I have a question regarding the 3th question you answered "Why do i have to create a private class called ViewHolder [...]" --> Why does it have to be a `class`? is it possible to make it a `public method` ?

Comment: Why do you want it to be a method? But, short answer, no. You can only pass objects to `setTag()`, so you have to define a class for your view holder.

Comment: I've had an older project where i made a public method called `myViews()` that i used in my `onCreate` method in an `if-statement`.. so i just wondered why i had to use `class` this time.

Comment: I think the major difference here is that, when you have just one Activity, you can use a method to organize all of your `findViewById()` calls... but in this case you have a _different_ view holder for _every_ row, so you need _many_ different "groups" of `findViewById()` calls. A view holder object/class is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A  `viewholder` is a design pattern used in android apps in order to replace the more expensive `findviewbyid` calls.

Quoting docs

Your code might call `findViewById()` frequently during the scrolling of ListView, which can slow down performance. Even when the Adapter returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. A way around repeated use of `findViewById()` is to use the "view holder" design pattern.

Regarding the second and third question the `settag` and `gettag` is basically a way for your view to have "memories" you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5291726/6453904) for further information and a more detailed explanation!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your input! I think i almost understood everything. I just need to verify one last question and i put that into Ben P. answer.