# How can I get the id of element in array of imageView Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an array of image Views which is generate dynamically on the run by the user

this is the code:

```
LinearLayout picLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cityInfoLN);
ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//lp.add
lp.setMargins(32, 8, 32, 8);
myImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
myImages[CityImageCount] = new ImageView(this);
myImages[CityImageCount].setId(CityImageCount);
myImages[CityImageCount] = myImage;
myImages[CityImageCount].setLayoutParams(lp);
myImages[CityImageCount].setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
myImages[CityImageCount].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        final View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setView(v1);

        Button btn = (Button) v1.findViewById(R.id.editBTN);
        final TextView editText = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText.setText("هل تريد تعديل أم حذف الصورة");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        alert.show();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view1) {
               // EditIndexs[]
              //  String name = v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
               // String name2 = context.getString(v.getId());
             //   String name3 = getString(view1.getId());
              //  String name4 = getResources().getString(view1.getId());

                EditIndex = CityImageCount;
                int xxx = view1.getId();
                showFile5();
                alert.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
});
picLL.addView(myImages[CityImageCount]);
```

My problem is when the user click on any of the images to edit or delete it. How can I know which image is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you didn't correctly set the image view with this code. It's because you set the ImageView to the array twice with different ImageView (Please read the comment in the code:

```
// You're creating a ImageView
ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.setMargins(32, 8, 32, 8);
myImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

// You're setting a new ImageView to array
myImages[CityImageCount] = new ImageView(this);
// then you set the Id
myImages[CityImageCount].setId(CityImageCount);

// But then you discard it by setting the array item with myImage
// so you're discarding the id.
myImages[CityImageCount] = myImage;
```

So, you need to set the ImageView to array like this:

```
ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.setMargins(32, 8, 32, 8);
myImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

myImages[CityImageCount] = myImage;
myImages[CityImageCount].setId(CityImageCount);
```

(Note: Instead of array, you can use ArrayList)

**Second**, you need to use [generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) or [ViewCompat.generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat#generateviewid) when setting the view id. You can't manually set view id with simple loop counter id like this:

```
myImages[CityImageCount].setId(CityImageCount);
```

it should be something like this:

```
// View.generateViewId() is only available from api 17
myImages[CityImageCount].setId(View.generateViewId());

// Use ViewCompat if you need to support API < 17
// myImages[CityImageCount].setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId());
```

**Third**, you need to handle the image click by checking the id:

```
 myImages[CityImageCount].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

    // Check the id
    String id = v.getId();

    ...
 }
```

In case you need specific key for the image, you can use [HashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap) instead of Array like this:

```
Map<String, ImageView> map = new HashMap<String, ImageView>();

...
ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
map.put("Id1",myImage);
```

**Last**, separate your logic to something like this:

```
private ImageView generateImageView() {
  ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);

  // set the ImageView properties here.
  ...

  return myImage;
} 

private void addImageViewToList(ImageView imageView) {
  // Add ImageView to the array
}

// hold previous click listener for ImageView.
private View.OnClickListener mImageViewClickListener;

// Get View.OnClickListener for ImageView, create it if not yet initialized.
private View.OnClickListener getImageViewClickListener() {
  if(mImageViewClickListener == null) {
     mImageViewClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
          // handle the ImageView click here
          ...
        }
  }
  return mImageViewClickListener;
}
```

So that you can arrange your code to something like this:

```
ImageView imageView = generateImageView();
imageView.setOnClickListener(getImageViewClickListener());
addImageViewToList(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTag() and getTag() methods of view might help you. here I paste the link of setTag() and getTag() usage.
[What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)