# Updating status of a button when button is pressed

Tags: android

"I have store 0 in Database now I want to update the status through 
`updateStatus()` when button is clicked.I am not sure that the query I have 
written is correct and I have no idea how to use `UpdateStatus()`."

"`onClick()` contains 5 buttons. e.g if the button `btn_AllCalls` is pressed then the status should be updated to var where var is the status I want to update.
but I have no idea how to do this.
`onclick()` function is used in another activity.
`GetButton` is Getters and Setter."

```
updateStatus(GetButton getButton){
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(STATUS, getButton.getStat());
        db.update(ACTIVETABLE,content,"STATUS = ?",null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_AllCalls:
            var = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_SpecificContactNumbers:
            var = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_UserInput:
            var = 3;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_UnknownNumbers:
            var = 4;
            break;
        case R.id.btn_SavedContacts:
            var = 5;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases there is a tag option. you may use it by getTag() and setTag()

Comment: How sir.Can you plz explain?

Comment: See this link @AdnanNawaz
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view