# Adding comment to View in Android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to add a comment to a view? So I can access it later and get the value of my comment.
I have a layout with lot of ImageViews and I'd like to link to some images songs uris. Is there any way to put these uris to views or I need to use something like dictionary?

Comment: You can store the uri as tag like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

Comment: @BömachtBlau thanks. That's what I need.